# Displaying php results inside a div

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Let me explain in detail what I want to achieve.
I have 3 pages: index.html, form.html and result.php. Using jquery when I click a button in index.html it will load form.html inside a div in index.html. form.html on submit calls result.php. What I want to achieve is when I click the submit button in form.html(loaded in index.html), the results from result.php to be displayed in the div from index.html where I loaded form.html. Below is the code for all 3 pages. Any help would be great.

index.html contents:

```
<html>
   <head>
       <title>index.html</title>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
   var theme = getTheme();
   $("#loadformbutton").jqxButton({ width: '120', height: '30', theme: theme });
   $("#loadformbutton").bind('click',function()
   {
        $('#div_for_form').load('form.html', function() {});
   });
   });
   </script>
   <div id="buttons">
      <input type="button" value="loadform" id='loadformbutton' />
   </div>
   <div id="div_for_form">
      Here loads form.html
   </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Contents of form.html:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>form.html</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form method="POST" action="result.php">
         <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass"/>
         <input type="submit" value="Ok" id="changepass"/>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Contents of result.php:

```
<?php
   $received=$_POST['pass'];
   echo 'Received: '.$received;
?>
```

At this moment it is functional but the results from result.php displays in a new page.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of submitting the form the normal way, consider calling result.php with Ajax (jQuery.post() for example). Then you can use the success-callback to inject the returned value.

Comment: @NullPointer already provided an example as an answer. That should give you at least some kind of starting point.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by jquery and ajax below is the simple way

Contents of result.php:

```
<?php
   $received=$_POST['pass'];
   echo 'Received: '.$received;
?>
```

make a ajax request like ,make a form id like id="from_one"

```
$("#from_one").submit(function(){
$.ajax({
  url: 'result.php',
  type: "POST",
  data:{pass:$('input[type=pass]')}
  success: function(data) {
     //here append the result to the div you want 
     // in data you will get the result 
  }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#changepass').click(function(){
var id = $('input#pass').val();
$.post( 'http://domain.com/result.php' { id : id },
        function(response){
            $('div#div_for_form').html(response);
        });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Include your results.php in the div to have it on the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Try below one :

in form.html change form tag :

```
<form method="POST" action="" onsubmit="return callphp()">
```

in index.html add function callphp() :

```
function callphp()
{
  var xmlhttp;
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
       xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
     else
        {
       xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
       if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
          {
         document.getElementById("div_for_form").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

      }
      }  
       xmlhttp.open("POST","result.php",true);
       xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
       xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: He deepi.I tryed your code and when i click the submit button the page goes back to it's firt state. I mean instead of the results from result.php inside the div i get "Here loads form.html. :(

Comment: onsubmit="callphp()" try with this

Comment: still nothing only  here loads form.html text.

Answer (score 0):

if you're planning to do a bigger project (more than just these two sites) I would recommend to create a **website template** (for your index.html)

you can find a good approach [here](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/how-to-create-php-website-template/)