# Get value without submitting it

Tags: php, jquery, html, post

I have a simple a+b php calculator, but you select the inputs from a dropdown.

```
<?php 
            if (isset($_POST['submit']) and ! empty($_POST['submit'])) {
                if (isset($_POST['radio'])) {
                    $radio_input = $_POST['radio'];
                    $radio_input1 = $_POST['radio1'];
                    echo "$";
                    echo  $radio_input1 + $radio_input;
                }
            }?>
        <form action="asdindex.php" method="post">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <select name="radio">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
            <select name="radio1">
                    <option value="1.2">1.2</option>
                    <option value="3.1">3.1</option>
                    <option value="0.3">0.3</option>
                    <option value="1.2">1.2</option>
                </select>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <input type= "submit" name="submit"value="submit"/>
    </form>
```

The question is how can i print the result without using a submit button/input/.
I know that you can't do it with PHP. But not sure how to do it with JQ or smt. else.

Comment: did you search SO?? `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339522/displaying-php-results-inside-a-div` or `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309844/displaying-php-results-on-current-page`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/kzb9enxn/)

You can use Javascript to do this. See the below JS

```
function addValues() {
  var a = 0,
    b = 0;
  var e = document.getElementById("radio");
  a = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  var e1 = document.getElementById("radio1");
  b = e1.options[e1.selectedIndex].value;
  alert(parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b));
}
```

Add the above JS inside a `<script>` before you close the `<body>`.

The function will be invoked by clicking a button. The HTML for button would be as follows

```
<button onclick="addValues()">Click to add</button>
```

**Update**

See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/kzb9enxn/1/)

---

Updated HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <select name="radio" id="radio">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
  </li>
  <li>
    <select name="radio1" id="radio1">
      <option value="1.2">1.2</option>
      <option value="3.1">3.1</option>
      <option value="0.3">0.3</option>
      <option value="1.2">1.2</option>
    </select>
  </li>
</ul>
<button onclick="addValues()">Click to add</button>
<br/> Result=
<span id="result"></span>
```

Updated JS

```
function addValues() {
  var a = 0,
    b = 0;
  var e = document.getElementById("radio");
  a = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  var e1 = document.getElementById("radio1");
  b = e1.options[e1.selectedIndex].value;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = (parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b));
}
```

**Update**

If you don't want the button, you can just listen for the `change` event of the `select`.

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/kzb9enxn/2/)

Comment: The point is to do it without a button, and not to alert it but to display it in the span

Comment: Instead of alerting the value, you can just set the value to a `<span>` using JS. Wiat..I'll update my answer..

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery, function can be executed on `change` of second `dropdown`,

sum gets calculated without hitting any button.

```js
$(function(){
    
    $('.check2').change(function(){
      var data1= parseInt($('.check1').val());
      var data2= parseInt($('.check2').val());
      alert(data1 + data2);            
    });
    
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="check1">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select class="check2">
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

use Ajax post selected option values to PHP and print the response